# I have installed virtualenvwrapper but getting error- workon: command not found

Tags: django, installation, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have just installed virtualenvwrapper by it [documentation site](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) and from link [http://www.openbookproject.net](http://www.openbookproject.net/courses/webappdev/units/webappdev2/resources/django_virtualenv.html)
but on running command-

`workon <vir.Env.Name>`
i am getting the following error-

`workon: command not found` The list of commands i used to install are-

```
    sudo aptitude install python-virtualenv
    sudo aptitude install python-dev
    mkdir mydjangoapp
    cd mydjangoapp/
    virtualenv --no-site-packages mydjangoappvenv
    virtualenv --no-site-packages jango
    source jango/bin/activate
    pip install virtualenv
    pip install virtualenvwrapper
    pip install --install-option="--user" virtualenvwrapper

    cat >> ~/.bash_profile
    export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
    export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/directory-you-do-development-in
    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I guess my virtualenvwrapper is not installed. Plz anybody can tell whats the problem.Also tell me what is .bash file and where it is found in our file directory.

Comment: Is the directory you do development in literally called `'directory-you-do-development-in'`?! And have you restarted `bash` so the new profile takes effect?

Comment: I have restarted the terminal after command  cat >> ~/.bash_profile .Actually i dont know much about bash. I guess i have to copy some lines-    (export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
    export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/directory-you-do-development-in
    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh  ) in my bash file but i dont know where bash file is located in system.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have installed virtualenvwrapper inside any virtual enviroment like this-

```
 rahul@rahulpc:~/mydjangoapp$ source jango/bin/activate
(jango)rahul@rahulpc:~/mydjangoapp$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

So before installing virtualenvwrapper you have to deactivate virtual enviroment.

```
(jango)rahul@rahulpc:~/mydjangoapp$ deactivate
rahul@rahulpc:~/mydjangoapp$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

now follow all further steps.